# creating a string by merging an int and a string

Tags: java

I have an int 50 (code calls this value) and a String F (code calls scale). I want to combine them and store a String 50F.

I keep getting a not a statement error.

A few things I have tried:

```
String new = (value + scale);
String new = value + " " + scale;
String new = value.concat(scale)
```

Comment: You can't have a variable named "new".

Comment: Don't use any of [java's keywords](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) as variable names or basically anything else besides what they are intended for.

Comment: how do you like my answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use the keyword `new` as a variable name.  Try something like

```
String str = value + scale;
```

The [Java tutorial on variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) states, towards the bottom:

> Also keep in mind that the name you choose must not be a keyword or reserved word.

[Here are Java's keywords](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html), and `new` is one of them.

Comment: how do you like my answer?

Answer (score 1):

**Another Flavor**

Code

```
  List<String> totallList =   Stream.of(Arrays.asList("50"),Arrays.asList("F"))
                                    .flatMap( string -> string.stream())
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
  totallList.forEach(System.out::print);
```

Output:

```
50F
```

Note **: I solved the question with Java 8 and I know it is a overkill but just another flavor**

don't ever use new to define your name variable because new is a reserved keyword